# lutorpy for shared memory between python and torch

Tags: python, lua, torch

I am trying to install lutorpy to load a network trained in torch and use it in python code. I get the following error:

```
lutorpy/_lupa.c:299:17: fatal error: lua.h: no such file or directory
```

I do have `lua.h`  in `torch/install/include` folder.

I'm following the instructions here and get this error:
https://github.com/imodpasteur/lutorpy

Answer (score 0):

Currently, lutorpy only support the standard torch installation, which means install torch in your home folder. So if that's the case for you, you problem mostly likely to be solved by start a new torch installation in your home folder.

In the meantime, you can track [this issue](https://github.com/imodpasteur/lutorpy/issues/9) for supporting arbitrary installation of torch.